# How to implement Application.Caller in Public Function

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

The below function takes the value in column F (currency ticker), and returns the function output (USD 20 dollar equivalent of input) in column H.

The issue is that the equation is not updating the value in column F when I drag the equation down column H (starting from H2).

Example: H2 = Oanda(F2)
When I drag this down (say to F10), the equation gives me the output for Oanda(F2) regardless of what the value is for F3-F10. I need some help implementing the Application.Caller feature here.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Oanda(ConvertWhat As String)

'References
'   Microsoft XML, vs.0
'   Microsoft Internet Controls
'   Microsoft HTML Object Library

Dim Conversion As String
Conversion = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee").Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Value2

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
'IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter?quote_currency=USD&base_currency=" & Conversion

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = ReadyState_Complete
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = IE.Document
Dim Ans As String
Ans = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(2).innerText)
Dim AnsExtract As Variant
AnsExtract = Split(Ans, " ")

Oanda = AnsExtract(4) * 20

End Function
```

Comment: The output isn’t the issue. The issue is the function doesn’t recognize which cell the function was called from thus returns the same value when dragged (or copied and pasted). It only recognizes the call cell when the equation is manually typed in.

Comment: if F2=EUR then L2=16.99. If F3=USD then L3=20. If I type the function into L2 and then drag down to L3, I get 16.99 for both cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the variable being passed into function

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Oanda(ByVal ConvertWhat As String) As Double

    'References
    '   Microsoft XML, vs.0
    '   Microsoft Internet Controls
    '   Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    'IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter?quote_currency=USD&base_currency=" & ConvertWhat

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = ReadyState_Complete
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.Document
    Dim Ans As String
    Ans = Trim$(Doc.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(2).innerText)
    Dim AnsExtract As Variant
    AnsExtract = Split(Ans, " ")

    Oanda = AnsExtract(4) * 20

End Function
```